# Optimizing using code motion

Tags: c, loops, optimization

I'm working on an assignment to optimize C code; the professor has implied that code motion should be the primary tool for this particular problem.

Here's the initial unoptimized code:

```
void naive_smooth(int dim, pixel *src, pixel *dst) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < dim; j++)
            dst[RIDX(i, j, dim)] = avg(dim, i, j, src);
}

typedef struct {
    unsigned short red;
    unsigned short green;
    unsigned short blue;
} pixel;

#define RIDX(i,j,n) ((i)*(n)+(j))

static pixel avg(int dim, int i, int j, pixel *src) {
    int ii, jj;
    pixel_sum sum;
    pixel current_pixel;
    initialize_pixel_sum(&sum);
    for(ii = max(i-1, 0); ii <= min(i+1, dim-1); ii++)
        for(jj = max(j-1, 0); jj <= min(j+1, dim-1); jj++)
            accumulate_sum(&sum, src[RIDX(ii, jj, dim)]);

    assign_sum_to_pixel(&current_pixel, sum);
    return current_pixel;
}

static void initialize_pixel_sum(pixel_sum *sum) {
    sum->red = sum->green = sum->blue = 0;
    sum->num = 0;
    return;
}

static void accumulate_sum(pixel_sum *sum, pixel p) {
    sum->red += (int) p.red;
    sum->green += (int) p.green;
    sum->blue += (int) p.blue;
    sum->num++;
    return;
}

static void assign_sum_to_pixel(pixel *current_pixel, pixel_sum sum) {
    current_pixel->red = (unsigned short) (sum.red/sum.num);
    current_pixel->green = (unsigned short) (sum.green/sum.num);
    current_pixel->blue = (unsigned short) (sum.blue/sum.num);
    return;
}
```

And here's the optimized version I've got so far:

```
void smooth(int dim, pixel *src, pixel *dst) {
    int i, j;
    int ii, jj;
    pixel_sum sum;
    pixel current_pixel;
    pixel p;
    int localDim = dim;
    for (i = 0; i < localDim; i++) {
        int dimi = localDim * i;
        int mini = min(i+1, localDim-1);
        int maxi = max(i-1, 0);
        for (j = 0; j < localDim; j++) {
            int minj = min(j+1, localDim-1);
            int maxj = max(j-1, 0);
            sum.red = sum.green = sum.blue = sum.num = 0;
            for(ii = maxi; ii <= mini; ii++) {
                int dimii = localDim * ii;
                for(jj = maxj; jj <= minj; jj++) {
                    p = src[dimii + jj];
                    sum.red += (int) p.red;
                    sum.green += (int) p.green;
                    sum.blue += (int) p.blue;
                    sum.num++;
                }
            }
            current_pixel.red = (unsigned short) (sum.red/sum.num);
            current_pixel.green = (unsigned short) (sum.green/sum.num);
            current_pixel.blue = (unsigned short) (sum.blue/sum.num);
            dst[dimi + j] = current_pixel;
        }
    }
}
```

The changes I've made to this so far are all things that I thought were supposed to be tenets of code motion optimization -- I've converted method calls (avg, initialize_pixel_sum, etc) to local code, created local versions of global variables (dim to localDim), and moved functions in loop definitions outside of the loops (the min and max functions as well as multiplications on dim/localDim). However, while the test suite that came with the assignment indicates that this is producing the same results as the original code, it is showing absolutely no change in the CPEs...so I've rewritten the code without causing any optimization effect.

I'm really perplexed as to why this is having no effect whatsoever, and would very much appreciate any insight as to what sort of code motion would cause a change in the CPE for this set of functions.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at what the compiler actually does to your original vs. new code?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm trying to do that now, using a gdb disassembler...haven't had any breakthroughs yet. Do you have any tips on what to look for in the disassembly to find the bottlenecks? Thanks. :)

Comment: gcc -S for the purpose of speeding the code up? Unfortunately, we're supposed to use a makefile provided by the professor to test our code so we can't change the compile command to affect our results. :/

Comment: No, gcc -S gives assembler output. `touch` your file, run make and see what the command line is, copy'n'paste the `gcc ... -c file.c -o file.o` or similar to your command line, go back and edit it to say `gcc ... -S file.c -o file.s` - now, file.s will have the assembler generated. Comparing that with the original code will give you an indication of how much the compiler has already moved code around.